# Incremental/decremental DB design

Tags: mysql, mongodb, list, database-design, database

My question is about a good design for a DB that will hold information about a list of items that can be incremented or decremented every X seconds. The idea is optimize it so there won't be duplicate information.

Example:

I have a script running every 5 seconds collecting information about the computers connected in a WiFi network and I want to store this information in a DB. I don't want to save anything in the DB in the case that in the scan `n` are the same users than in the scan `n-1`.

Is there any specific DB design that can be useful to store information about a new wifi client connected to the network or about an existent wifi client that left it?

What kind of DB is better for this kind of incremental/decremental use case?

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Why do think that any regular database setup would not be able to handle your usage?  Also, you tagged with both MySQL and Mongo, which are very different technologies.  Do you plan on using SQL or NoSQL?

Comment: What are you going to use to identify your WiFi clients? Is that something you can use as the key of your table? Then you only need to run a insert-on-duplicate-key-update operation and you will be fine: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the question is about what is the best DB for this problem, so I'm open to SQL and NoSQL.

Comment: @JosepValls I need to keep track of a user not longer being in the network so your solution does not work

Answer (score 0):

If this is like "up votes" or "likes", then the one piece of advice is to use a 'parallel' table to hold just the counter and the id of the item.  This will minimize interference (locking) whenever doing the increment/decrement.

Meanwhile, if you need the rest of the info on an item, plus the counter, then it is simple enough to `JOIN` the two tables.

If you have fewer than a dozen increments/decrements per second, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It is not like "up votes". It is, as I said in the question, to keep track of the time when a user connected and disconnected from a wifi network. We can presume that the key is the MAC address of the device that connects or disconnects.

Comment: Do you have tentative SQL for the cron job?